# How to loop over C-array using embed assembler (aarch64)?

Tags: c, clang, qemu, arm64, assemble

I have the next awful code:

```
void print(const char* text) {
    unsigned long address = 0x9000000;
    unsigned long counter = 0;
    char ch = *text;
    while (ch != '\0') {
        address += counter;
        asm volatile(
            "MOV X10, %[address];"
            "MOV W9, %w[ch];"
            "STRB W9, [X10];"
            :[address]"+r"(address), [ch]"+r"(ch)
        );
        ++counter;
        ch = *(text + counter);
    }
}

void start(void) {
    print("Hello, World!");
}
```

Unfortunately, even this code doesn't work correctly and prints: `Hel` instead of `Hello, World!`

However, I would prefer to re-write all loop logic in the embed/inline assembler but I can't get **how to read and iterate over C-array (`text`) in assembler**. I've tried a lot of variants and all successfully failed.

This code was created for aarch64 (cortex-a72) and it's launched in Qemu by command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt \
    -cpu cortex-a72 \
    -bios "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qemu/$(QEMU_VERSION)/share/qemu/edk2-aarch64-code.fd" \
    -m 128M \
    -nographic \
    -device loader,file=$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.elf \
    -device loader,addr=0x40100000,cpu-num=0
```

**P.S.** I use LLVM clang and aarch64-elf-binutils compilers and linker on macOS (M1 Pro) to build `kernel.elf`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, maybe someone is the same noobie like me and it will help him.

Firstly, the solution:

```
void print(const char* text) {
    unsigned long address = 0x9000000;
    asm volatile(
        "MOV X10, %[address];"
        "MOV X11, %[text];"
        :[address]"+r"(address), [text]"+r"(text)
    );
PRINT_STR:
    asm volatile(
        "LDR X9, [X11];"
        "STRB W9, [X10];"
        "ADD X11, X11, #0x1;"
    );
    asm goto ("CBNZ W9, %l0"::::PRINT_STR);
}

void start(void) {
    print("Hello, World!");
}
```

**How does it work?**

1. Declare the address of video memory (fix me, plz, if I am wrong). In our case is `0x9000000`.
2. Load `address` and `text` variables into `X10` and `X11` registers (there is no strict rules which registers you will use). Note `text` is a pointer so in fact we loaded an address of our string into register, not a value.
3. Declare a label to jump into it later.
4. Load into `X9` register the next string character that's located by an address in `X11` register.
5. Copy the loaded value to `0x9000000`.
6. Increment `X11` register's value, in other words we just switch our pointer to the next character in the string.
7. Finally, jump into `PRINT_STR` if the `W9` register contains non-zero value (C-strings end with `\0`).

**UPD:**
Second thoughts are best... I wanted to use assembler due to I thought C code will be ugly and still mixed with assembler. But I forgot it's mr. "C", pointers are the power!

```
void print(const char * text) {
    char * address = (char *)0x9000000;
    const char * ch = text;
    while (*ch != '\0') {
        *address = *ch;
        ++ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there are many bugs in your inline asm.  First, it is not safe to assume that `X10` and `X11`, nor any other registers for that matter, will remain unchanged in between your `asm` blocks.  The compiler owns all the registers and is at complete liberty to do with them as it pleases outside each asm block.  You also are not allowed to overwrite those registers (or any other) without declaring them as clobbered.

Comment: Also, the middle block, which reads and writes memory, needs a `memory` clobber.  If this function is inlined into another function, any writes to the string being printed could be reordered with this function, since you have not told the compiler that you read from the string.  A last bug is that your asm version outputs the null byte that terminates the string, which I suspect you don't want.

Comment: The C version is much more sensible, but you do need to declare `address` as `volatile`, otherwise the compiler might optimize out all stores but the last as "dead".  You could also write it a little more concisely and idiomatically as `for ( ; *text ; text++) *address = *text;`  Or, `for (size_t i = 0; text[i]; i++) *address = text[i];`.  You don't need the extra variable `ch` since a function parameter acts as a perfectly good local variable.

Comment: If you did want to write it in assembly, I would simply write the entire function in asm, either in its own `.s` file, or as an `__attribute__((naked))` function in a `.c` file.  Then you own all the call-clobbered registers for the duration of the function.

Comment: Wait a second, are you intending to write every byte at the same address `0x9000000`, as if it's a hardware output register, or should they be written to successive addresses, as for video RAM?  If the latter, then you need to increment `address` also on each iteration, or use the same index for both: `for (size_t i = 0; text[i]; i++) address[i] = text[i];`

Answer (score 1):

`address` is not incremented properly.

Let us view this with printing to `stdout`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_print(const char* text) {
    unsigned long address = 0x9000000;
    unsigned long counter = 0;
    char ch = *text;
    while (ch != '\0') {
        address += counter;
#if 0
        asm volatile(
            "MOV X10, %[address];"
            "MOV W9, %w[ch];"
            "STRB W9, [X10];"
            :[address]"+r"(address), [ch]"+r"(ch)
        );
#endif
        printf("ch:%3d %c address:%lX counter:%lX\n", ch, ch, address, counter);
        ++counter;
        ch = *(text + counter);
    }
}

//void start(void) {
int main(void) {
  my_print("Hello, World!");
}
```

Output

```
ch: 72 H address:9000000 counter:0
ch:101 e address:9000001 counter:1
ch:108 l address:9000003 counter:2
ch:108 l address:9000006 counter:3
ch:111 o address:900000A counter:4
ch: 44 , address:900000F counter:5
ch: 32   address:9000015 counter:6
ch: 87 W address:900001C counter:7
ch:111 o address:9000024 counter:8
ch:114 r address:900002D counter:9
ch:108 l address:9000037 counter:A
ch:100 d address:9000042 counter:B
ch: 33 ! address:900004E counter:C
```

I suspect OP only wants `address` changed by 1 *after* printing.

```
// address += counter;
++address;  // Move to after "asm volatile" printing.
```

```
    while (ch != '\0') {
        asm volatile(
            "MOV X10, %[address];"
            "MOV W9, %w[ch];"
            "STRB W9, [X10];"
            :[address]"+r"(address), [ch]"+r"(ch)
        );
        ++address;
        ++counter;
        ch = *(text + counter);
    }
```